# Reduce image size by reducing color

Tags: vb.net

I have to create a program that reduces image size by reducing color. I got this code from my friend. Can you check it out? Thank you for your help.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog()
        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(ofd.FileName)
            PictureBox.Image = bmp
            Dim width As Integer = bmp.Width
            Dim height As Integer = bmp.Height
            Dim bmr As New Bitmap(height, height)
            For i = 0 To width - 1
                For j = 0 To height - 1
                    Dim a,b,c As Integer
                    Dim color As New Color
                    color = bmp.GetPixel(i, j)
                    a = color.a / 2
                    b = color.b  / 2
                    c = color.c / 2

                    bmr.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(a,b,c ))
                    a = 0 : b = 0 : c = 0
                Next
            Next
            PictureBox2.Image = bmr
            bmr.Save("image2.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog()
        Dim imgSource As String
        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            imgSource = ofd.FileName
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(ofd.FileName)
            PictureBox.Image = bmp
            Dim wid As Integer = ((bmp.Width / 2) + 1)
            Dim hgt As Integer = ((bmp.Height / 2) + 1)
            Dim bmr As New Bitmap(wid, hgt)
            For i = 0 To wid - 2
                For j = 0 To hgt - 2
                    Dim a,b,c  As Integer
                    For x = 0 To 1
                        For y = 0 To 1
                            Dim cc As New Color
                            cc = bmp.GetPixel(i * 2 + x, j * 2 + y)
                            a += cc.a
                            b += cc.b
                            c += cc.c
                        Next
                    Next
                    a = a / 4
                    b = b / 4
                    c = c / 4
                    bmr.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(a,b,c ))
                    a = 0 : b = 0 : c = 0
                Next
            Next
            PictureBox1.Image = bmr
            bmr.Save("test.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That's not c#, it's VB. Do you have to rewrite it in c#?

Comment: @CodeFromItaly Rewrite or create a new code to reduce size by color up to u i just need code reduce size by color

Comment: "reduce image size by color"  - do you want to reduce the number of colours, or do you want to resize the image to make it smaller?

Comment: @AndrewMorton bro the Q said Compress an image by compressing image colors

Comment: Voting to close this question, it belongs on Code Review not SO. SO is not a code checking site unlike code review which semi is.